# Finding impedance Z and \$ \cos (\alpha) \$ in RLC circuit

Tags: impedance

I would like to have some help with this problem:

U = 93 [V]

f = 600 [Hz]

L = 0,24 [H]

C = 0,16 [μF]

R = 950 [Ω]

[image]

This is the RCL circuit which I need to find the impedance \$Z\$ in and \$\cos(\alpha)\$

The first two questions that I had was to find the inductive reactance, XL, and the capacitive reactance, XC. I figured them out and I got XL = 905 ohm and XC = 1658 ohm.

I thought that I would use this formula:

$$\mathrm{impedance} \, Z = \sqrt{R^2+(X_L-X_C)^2}$$

But I can't get it right. 
I would also like to know if \$\cos(\alpha)\$ is solved through \$\cos(\alpha) = \frac{R}{Z}\$

Comment: You haven't defined what "alpha" indicates. (By the way you can write \$\alpha\$ as `\$\alpha\$`). Is it the real part of Z? Is it the phase of some signal?

Comment: Also, I would use \$Z = R + j(X_L-X_C)\$. The formula you give is for the magnitude of the impedance (\$\left|Z\right|\$), not the impedance itself.

Comment: I didn't get \$\alpha\$\ defined from the question..Ok, and should I consider j as sqrt(-1)?:)

Comment: Yes, \$j\$ is the usual symbol for the imaginary unit in EE.

Comment: So if I want to calculate Z, should it be Z = 950 + (sqrt(-1))*(905-1658)?

Comment: @ThePhoton are you sure your formula is correct? That looks like formula for a series RLC to me and the R is in parallel with the LC, not in series.

Comment: @WarrenHill I'm thinking the same..I don't seem to get the correct answer

Comment: Yes (@WarrenHill), the main point is that impedance is a complex number, not a real number. OP, you need to use the rules for combining elements in series and parallel to combine the impedances of the inductor, capacitor, and resistor.

Answer (score 1):

If we consider this to be a circuit to have two parallel legs then the first is the series LC combination which has impedance \$ Z_1 = j \cdot (X_L - X_c) \$ , The second is \$ Z_2 = R \$

Now the simplest formula for two parallel paths is \$ Z = \frac{Z_1 \cdot Z_2}{Z_1 + Z_2} \$

Putting these together we have \$ Z = \frac{R \cdot j\cdot (X_L - X_C)}{R + j(X_L - X_C)}\$

Which is a little messy because we have \$ j = \sqrt{-1} \$ on both top and bottom of the fraction. Note in pure math \$ i \$ is used instead of \$ j \$ but in electronics \$ i \$ usually referrers to a current.

The best way to get rid of the imaginary part on the bottom is to multiply top and bottom by 1 in the form of the complex conjugate of the denominator.

So we have

\$ Z = \frac{R \cdot j\cdot (X_L - X_C)}{R + j(X_L - X_C)} \cdot \frac{R - j(X_L - X_C)}{R - j(X_L - X_C)}\$

I'll leave the rest as an exercise from here but assuming \$ \alpha \$ is the phase angle then \$ \alpha = atan\left( \frac{\text{imaginary_part}}{\text{real_part}}\right) \$ and

\$ |Z| = \sqrt{\text{real_part}^2 + \text{imaginary_part}^2}\$

Comment: Note you are using a different sign convention for defining \$Z_C\$ than OP seems to have been using.

Comment: Am I thinking right if my new Z = R^2 *(Xl-Xc)^2 / R^2(Xl-Xc)?

Comment: @Rodbeh Z is a complex number  and has both real and imaginary parts. |Z| is the magnitude of Z i.e. just the size ignoring any phase shift. It is important to distinguish between the two.

Comment: @WarrenHill thank you so much!! finally solved it!